# Than vs. Than the one of

Tags: expression-choice

What is correct/preferable and why?

a) "The error of the first model is lower than the one of the second model."

or

b) "The error of the first model is lower than the second model."

To me, a) sounds more natural but also overcomplicated.

Thanks!

Comment: "... the one of ..." is necessary here, it's not complicated or unnatural, just that in conversation, people tend to use the second form that is incorrect.

Comment: "My dog runs faster than my neighbor"

Comment: (a') 'The error of the first model is lower than that of the second." Though 'of' should perhaps be 'in'.

Comment: Shouldn't we have another option for 'error... is low/ lower'? Can't it better be, 'The level of error is low/ lower...'? Not sure; I could be wrong too.